# Azure Service Fabric join Virtual network

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-virtual-network

Is it possible to join a Azure Service Fabric Cluster to a Virtual Network in Azure ?

Not simply join an existing Virtual Network, but also join the vm's where the cluster is running on into the domain. So that the cluster can use an domain user account to access network shares etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The default SF template creates a VNET for the cluster, so I assume you mean join to an existing VNET.

If you take a look at the [sample template for SF](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/service-fabric-unsecure-cluster-5-node-1-nodetype/azuredeploy.json), you can see the `subnet0Ref` variable which is being used to set the network profile of the NICs that are part of the newly created scale set. You can modify the template to lookup your pre-existing subnet using the `resourceid` template expression function ([documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-template-functions/#resourceid)). Then you can just drop all the other resources from the template that you don't need created, like the VNET itself.

Comment: I've edited my question, perhaps you can edit your answer :) It is more a issue with joining an existing domain.

Comment: Oh well, you gave answer to my first question and I didn't asked it fully, +1 anyway :)

Comment: Thanks.. I haven't done it myself, but I would try customizing the SF ARM template to include the AD domain extension: `JsonADDomainExtension`. https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-vm-domain-join/azuredeploy.json Did you try that?

Comment: For now I went another route, the one I believe that our customers will have. They will most likely setup their own cluster environment on windows servers. So I manually created 3 VM's in azure and joined the domain with them. Now I'm  configuring the cluster to work on the 3 VM's. Not as fancy, but it match more with our customers that will run our applications. It is just a test environment anyway. PS: Wow I'm more being a operator than a developer these days.

Comment: Anyway I think I could setup a ARM template by deploying one manually in azure and capture that template from the VM. Then use it as a base for the cluster template, but that is something for in the future.

Comment: is it possible to join an existing Virtual Network by using the Service Fabric creation process in Azure portal? I can't see settings that would allow me to include the cluster into an existing VN

Comment: @RichardLenoir no there's is not (as of today at least).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the document highlighting how to use and Existing Virtual Network / Subnet that was written by our support engineer. 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kwill/2016/10/05/azure-service-fabric-common-networking-scenarios/

We are merging this content into our official documentation. sorry about the delay.