# Service Fabric Cluster attached to an existing Virtual Network

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-virtual-network

Is it possible to join an existing Virtual Network when using the Service Fabric cluster creation process in Azure portal? I can't see settings that would allow me to include the cluster into an existing VN.

From what I've understood, each node type is associated to a scale set and a VN.

There's a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842763/azure-service-fabric-join-virtual-network), but it deals with ARM templates, not the portal creation process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not (as of today at least)

Comment: thanks, this means that in order to have VMs in the same Virtual Network as a Service Fabric's nodes, the Service Fabric cluster has to be created prior to everything else

Comment: I would recommend using the ARM template and adjusting it to your needs. It takes some getting used to but it has many advantages as you will most likely run into scenarios where you want to change some parts of your setup (e.g. load balancer rules). Also by default, everything is public - for a secure setup you should use VPN and internal load balancers wherever possible

Comment: @RichardLenoir not necessarily. VNET is an independent resource in Azure and can be created alone, or with other resources. The default SF template creates a VNET for you, and most VM templates also. What you can do instead is created a VNET in advance - through the UI \ template \ command, it's up to you. Then whenever you create a new resource, just associate it with that VNET. So the only thing that has to be created prior is the VNET.

Comment: @itaysk, how would you then associate a cluster's node to an existing VNET in the UI? It only works via ARM, right?

Comment: @RichardLenoir You are correct, currently the Portal's UI for SF doesn't allow you to choose to connect to existing VNET. What I meant for in the previous comment was to give an example where SF is created last, not first as you assumed. In example (1) create VNET. (2) create VMs in that VNET. (3) create SF in that VNET (using ARM).

Comment: Also, you can create an ARM template that is configured to join an existing VNET, and take the VNET name and settings as a template parameter. If provision that template via the portal, it will automatically detect that parameter and create a GUI for you to enter these values. It's not as nice as the built in SF creation UI, but it is some kind of UI driven method to achieve your goal